# calling a class with ajax

Tags: php, ajax

I need some help with this please
I can't get a handle on it.

The problem is that I want to call a class method, in this case with static methods with an ajax call.

I have put the helper class in the same folder as the script that is called by ajax for easy referencing and try to include it.
Could it be that my refencing is wrong?

If I make a testclass in the file that is called by ajax I can get a response.

```
class test {
    public function testit() {
        return "testit";
    }
}
$t=new test;
$check= $t->testit();



switch($action) {
case "someaction":
    $data = array();
    $file='input_helper.php';
    include_once $file;

    $check= input_helper::ip_address();
    header('Content-type: application/json');

    $output = array(
        "check" => $check,
        "user" => $data
        );

    echo json_encode($output);

    exit(0); // Stop script.

    break;
//...
```

**EDIT FOR MORE CLARIFICATION**

The action is set as a post variable in the ajax function
The ajax url points to a script that takes some action based on the posted variables

thanks, Richard

Comment: How are you setting `$action`? How does the request specify what method to call? Does it name the class and method? From the sample, it looks like the request gives some string naming the action to take, and the script is responsible for picking the class and method. Is this correct?

Comment: Thats correct, I try'd to run the ajax call threw the mvc structure by specifying the complete url...domain/controller/method, BUT I only got back some html in the response and not my variable. Side effect is that I bypass the autoload functions hence my initial issue.Mayby I can set them up in this script again.And use this script as a handler for ajax requests. If anyone has any feedback how I could run the ajax requests according to normal mvc paradigim, that would be helpfull.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
  include_once 'your/class/path/helper_class.php';
  .
  .
```

at the top of your PHP page should do it. it really has nothing to do with AJAX. If your PHP file is in fact being hit on the callback, then that should work properly.

Optionally, to test that your path is correct, if you do:

```
 <?php 
     require 'your/class/path/helper_class.php';
     .
     .
```

If the path is not correct PHP will throw a fatal **E_ERROR** level error.

Comment: or perhaps: include_once 'your/class/path/input_helper.php'; It's more concrete, and include_once is not a function.

Comment: thanks, I finally cleaned out the whole class and only put the testit() in it and it works. Something in the class must have caused it. Just for clarity, spl_register does not work anymore I guess if I call the script without the www.domain controller/function methodology. Or should I give that url to the ajax call, so that it will automaticly instantiates the objects again?

Comment: in other words, create an ajax controller with methods and do a 
$.ajax({
url: "www.domain/ajaxcontroller/testit",

Comment: @Richard - yes I think creating a controller to handle that functionality is a good idea

Comment: I try'd that, the problem is that the frontcontroller is also instantiated and it creates html output in the response(firebug). Because at the end off the index I have echo $frontctrl->getBody()
How can you fire an ajax controller without causing this? I have to look into that.